# PHP unlink() not working to delete files

Tags: php, mysql

I am have been trying to setup this code to delete a row on the mysql database as well as the photo that was uploaded with it. It is working GREAT to remove the row data, but it will not get rid of the photo, and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. To simplify things, im using the variable $id which is the number of the row entered in the form which triggers this php file:

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="blahblah_plans"; // Mysql username
$password="password"; // Mysql password
$db_name="blahtbl_name"; // Database name
$tbl_name="plans"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// get value of id that sent from address bar
$id=$_GET['idnum'];

$compositesql="SELECT composite FROM plans WHERE ID ='$id'";

$compositeresult = mysql_query($compositesql) or die(mysql_error());

$compositefilename = "/composite/" + $compositeresult;

$unlink = unlink($compositefilename);

if($unlink) {

echo 'Successfully deleted file: ';
echo $compositefilename;

} else {

echo 'Error deleting file: ';
echo $compositefilename;

}

// Delete data in mysql from row that has this id
$sql="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE ID ='$id'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
header("location:planentry.php");
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php
// close connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Do you have `chmod` delete access?

Comment: Does www-data have writing permission on the folder you are trying to access? Does unlink produce any error? Try echoing unlink($compositefilename) to check for an error code

Comment: Will not fix your problem, however this won't work `header("location:planentry.php");` it needs a space after the colon, such as `header("location: planentry.php");`

Comment: assuming you have rights ... have you tried to use file_exists to make sure the file is where you expect it?

Comment: The path you are unlinking is constructed to be `/composite/filename`. I doubt you are really storing the images in the root folder of your server.

Comment: The way you construct your query is vulnerable to sql injection. Also, the old mysql extension is deprecated. Please have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: What is this??? `$compositeresult = mysql_query($compositesql)` It is not the value of your query but a resource. And also do you want to delete by id or by the column named `composite`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `$compositeresult` contains a resource rather than a result set. This line is what's causing it:

```
$compositeresult = mysql_query($compositesql) or die(mysql_error());
```

To fix that, store the resource on a variable, then store the result set on another variable, like this:

```
$compositequery = mysql_query($compositesql) or die(mysql_error());
$compositeresult = mysql_fetch_array($compositequery) or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, I highly recommend that you start using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql`, since it's safer. Also, as xdazz said, PHP's concatenation operator is the dot, not the plus sign. So your `$compositefilename` should be declared as (note that `$compositeresult` is an array of data and therefore should have its correct key explicitly written):

```
$compositefilename = "/composite/" . $compositeresult['composite'];
```

Comment: Thank you! This along with adding this: $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
  
$compositefilename = $root . "/composite/" . $compositeresult['composite']; worked!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the path is right, `$compositefilename = "/composite/" + $compositeresult;` should be the path in the server, it most likely to be

`$compositefilename = PATH_TO_YOUR_WEB_ROOT . "/composite/" . $compositeresult;`

And php does not use `+` to concat strings.

Comment: changed that like suggested without the "+" replacing with a "." and error is now: "Error deleting file: /composite/Resource id #2 " I did not add PATH_TO_YOUR_WEB_ROOT as I am unfamiliar with how that should appear.

Comment: @Dustin If you were to read some of the comments underneath your question, it may give you more insight as to what is happening, or what is NOT happening.